# Function with generic parameter

Tags: c#

I am looking to do this:

```
public void MyFunction<T<TItem>>() where ....
{

}
```

the above syntax does not work, but is this possible?

Comment: I'm sort of confused about what you are looking for.  You can do `public void MyFunction<TInterface, TItem>() where TInterface : T<ITem> { }`.  Is that what you want? e.g. `public void MyFunction<TCollection, TItem>() where TCollection : ICollection<TItem> { }`.

Comment: Seems like he's looking for generic associated types. dbc has the right idea though.